# Does PHP have a terse way of creating a "lazy array"?

Tags: php, arrays

I want a terse way of doing something like this.

```
$this->requireAllConditionsAreTruthy([
    function() { return $this->clan },
    function() { return $this->team },
    function() { return $this->memberToAdd },
    function() { return $this->section },
    function() { return $this->clan->hasTeamForSection($this->section) },
    function() { return $this->memberToAdd->isInClan($this->clan) },
    function() { return ! $this->team->hasMember($this->memberToAdd) },
    function() { return ! $this->memberToAdd->isOnTeamForSection($this->section) }
]);
```

The purpose being that if something like `$this->clan` turns out to be falsey, I want to be able to throw an exception and log which condition failed and drop out of the array iteration before calling `$this->clan->hasTeamForSection`.

Does PHP have a terse way of defining a lazy-evaluated array?

Comment: I don't know if "terse" has a specific connotation in some circles, but it doesn't feel like the right word for this scenario. You are basically wanting some kind of "short circuiting" mechanism, similar to how `if ( $this->clan && $this->clan->hasTeamForSection ) ` would halt before evaluating the second bit because the first bit is false, is that the idea? Does this exist in another language that you are aware of?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the most straight forward solution is to yield each expression and treat the method like a generator. Using `yield`, each expression will be lazy-evaluated only when it's looped over.

```
public function authorization() {

    yield $this->clan;
    yield $this->team;
    yield $this->memberToAdd;
    yield $this->section;
    yield $this->clan->hasTeamForSection($this->section);
    yield $this->memberToAdd->isInClan($this->clan);
    yield  ! $this->team->hasMember($this->memberToAdd);
    yield  ! $this->memberToAdd->isOnTeamForSection($this->section);
}
```

Then to process the authorization, I can do this:

```
public function authorize() {

    foreach ($this->authorization() as $key => $condition) {

        if (!$condition) {
           Log::debug(sprintf("Authorization condition %s failed in %s", $key, get_class($this));
           throw new AuthorizationException;
        }
     }
 }
```

That will keep the authorization validation to a minimum, while still providing more precise feedback about which condition failed, for debugging or general logging purposes.